# Unable to read kafka topic from Drill

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-drill

We are working on adding an `SQLEngine` - Apache drill on top of `Kafka` and enable query access for troubleshooting purposes.

Here is the `Kafka` configuration

```
{
  "type": "kafka",
  "kafkaConsumerProps": {
    "security.protocol": "SSL",
    "enable.auto.commit": "true",
    "value.deserializer": "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer",
    "group.id": "drill-consumer",
    "auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
    "ssl.truststore.location": "kafka.truststore.jks",
    "bootstrap.servers": "abc1:9911,abc2:9911,abc3:9911",
    "ssl.truststore.password": "abcdef",
    "key.deserializer": "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer"
  },
  "enabled": true
}
```

we are able to connect to `Kafka` and read topics

```
show tables;
```

However when we query a topic

```
select * from kafka.testtopic limit 10;
```

we are getting below error message

> org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: DATA_READ ERROR: Failure while reading messages from kafka. Recordreader was at record: 1
>   com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 10 Fragment 0:0
>   [Error Id: 1728b1e7-ba2a-4750-895f-285743e05301 on hostname:31010]

Comment: Drill can only read json messages. What data is in the topic?

Comment: It is indeed JSON Messages.

Comment: According to the error, MalformedJsonException suggests otherwise. Can you show some messages from the topic outside of drill?